# MultiThreaded solution to avoid DialogBox pausing execution

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, automation

I am currently automating a series of calls to a library in VB.NET consoleApplication. The functioncalls usually require a series of user selected inputs. My problem with this is that a set of these functions create a programmatically inaccessible DialogBox instance and pauses the execution of the program until they have been interacted with.

Right now I have tried to solve this problem by using multiple threads according to the code below.

```
Public Sub StartFormFunction(ByVal inputValue As String)
       frameWork.showHiddenDialogBox(inputValue)
End Sub

Public Sub threadFunction(ByValue inputValue As String)
    Dim nrOfOpenForms As Integer = Application.OpenForms.Count()       
    Try               
        Dim t As New Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf StartFormFunction))
        t.Priority = Threading.ThreadPriority.Highest
        t.Start(inputValue)
        'Wait until the prompt has been created.            
        While (Application.OpenForms.Count() = nrOfOpenForms) And (t.IsAlive)
        End While        
        if Not t.IsAlive Then
            log.Error("Thread did not open dialogBox")
            Return
        End If
        'Select preffered button on dialogBox
        Dim isFinished As Boolean = False
        For Each curForm As Form In Application.OpenForms
            For Each btn As Button In curForm.Controls.OfType(Of Button)
                If btn.Name = "Button3" Then
                    btn.PerformClick()
                    isFinished = True
                Exit For
            End If
            Next
            if isFinished Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        'Wait until thread completed Function
        While t.IsAlive
        End While

        Catch ex As Exception        
            log.Error("Thread Error")
        End Try
End Sub
```

I have not found a way to use Control.Invoke() in a console application yet and is because of this the reason it is not used. 
The way I can get my code to be able to execute completely is to disable `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` which I am trying to avoid.

Is it possible to solve the problem of accessing a DialogBox without using multiple threads? If not, is the problem solvable by invoking the subcall?

**EDIT**
Some of my description might have been lacking in detailed information. 
My problem is that my application run a method `showHiddenDialogBox()`, that run a set of instructions in a class that is kept out of scope from my code. This inaccessible class displays a form when all functionality have been executed. When this form is shown the application pause all execution of code until a user is promoting a input. 
This makes it necessary to use multiple threads to get around. However this new thread will own this form while it is displayed an all of the content. This included in the buttons that I would need the other thread to access.

Comment: Your question is lacking information. What does `frameWork.showHiddenDialogBox(inputValue)` do? When do you need to invoke? I don't see any multithreaded code that would require invoking. -- You say want to open a form but not have it block execution, so you're likely calling `Form.ShowDialog()` instead of `Form.Show()`.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail. The ShowHiddenDialogBox is a method who commits a series of changes to a class that is inaccessible for me. This method execute operations and displays a messagebox in the end that will break execution of code until a button have been clicked. This is a form instance that exists outside of my scope and is inaccessible. My goal for now is to execute this method with a thread that can be "locked" when the form appear while another thread is committing an input to close the form and releasing the thread.

Comment: That's a tough problem to deal with, what you'd have to do is invoke the entire `For Each btn` loop. Use Tyler's code but only invoke the current form and do your stuff in a multiline `Sub()`.

Comment: This would be a good solution, if I have understood the approach correctly this would have the problem of freezing the application. To be able to iterate over the forms buttons we need an active instance of the form. To have a active instance of the form we are required to have a separate thread that is creating the form or lock the current thread that prevent us from iterating.

Comment: But you are already iterating the forms' buttons, what's the problem with adding the invoke there (which is what I meant)? Your application is already blocked by your `While` and `For`-loops. If you don't want it to be blocked start yet another thread.

Comment: FYI `Control.Invoke()` only blocks the thread it's called in, not the entire app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use "CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls", just invoke a control with this code:

```
'Insert this in a module
<Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
Public Sub InvokeCustom(ByVal Control As Control, ByVal Action As Action)
    If Control.InvokeRequired Then Control.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub() Action()), Nothing) Else Action.Invoke()
End Sub
```

The call this sub for every control in a thread

```
textbox1.InvokeCustom(sub() textbox1.text = "abc")
```

Comment: @VisualVincent as you can see `Control.Invoke(Action)` is already in the sub, that anyway check is an invoke is required. For the multiple control, you are right but i had problem with a form that contain a Panel or a TableLayout. For the speed... depend of how many controls he have, if are more than 10 (at the same time) of corse is better to invoke a Form, but if there are 2 or 3.. why invoke a complete form?

Comment: (Rewrote my comment to make it sound less harsh) May I ask why you are creating a `MethodInvoker` delegate _and_ a lambda expression method to invoke the action, when you can just call `Control.Invoke(Action)` :)? Also, if he's updating multiple UI elements at the same time he'd better call `Form.InvokeCustom` and use a multiline lambda inside, instead of invoking for every control since each Invoke takes a bit of time to execute.

Comment: `but if there are 2 or 3.. why invoke a complete form?` - The `Control.Invoke()` method will look for the parent form and invoke that anyway. The only time difference would be the time it takes to find the absolute parent, since invoking just puts messages in the UI threads queue (which all controls and forms run in).

Comment: `as you can see Control.Invoke(Action) is already in the sub, that anyway check is an invoke is required` - I know what the check is for, but you're creating both a `MethodInvoker` and a `Sub()` lambda instead of just calling `Control.Invoke(Action)` with your `Action` parameter directly. :)

Comment: @VisualVincent i have never test to call a parent control instead of a single child control, i will do it. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I just lied a little... Apparently `Invoke()` does not look for the absolute parent, only the parent that has had its window handle created _**if**_ the current control hasn't. Thus invoking the entire form or a single control doesn't matter. Result and speed will be the same.